# Quartz composer video recorder

Tags: video-capture, video-recording, quartz-composer

I would like to create a Quartz composer that can record 10 seconds of video from a camera 
and then play back that video forward or backwards or with effects. Any pointers? A patch or plugin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can record video by connecting the `Video Input` patch to the built-in `Queue` patch.  Then use `Structure Index Member` to access various frames in the captured video.

Comment: thakxs a lot i allmost get it 
im new at QC but now i can almost finish it

Answer (score 0):

There's also a plugin called "Sampler" you can download here : http://kriss.cx/tom/tag/quartz-composer/